# REPLACE function SYBASE doesn't work

Tags: sybase, str-replace

The replace function is not working with Sybase. I tried with the function str_replace but I had an error too. I need to replace all carriage returns and Lines feeds from the field "LIGTXT" by " -" .

`SELECT str_replace(LIGTXT,char(10)+char(13), ' - ' ) as COMMENT FROM TXTENT`

=> Function REPLACE invoked with wrong number or type of argument(s).

Can you please help me ?

Comment: What is the error for  str_replace function? What type is `LIGTXT` column?

Comment: The error is 'Function REPLACE invoked with wrong number or type of argument(s).' It's a text field.

Comment: `Function REPLACE invoked with wrong number or type of argument(s).` message is for `REPLACE` function, but I want to see message for `str_replace` function

Comment: We are missing some specifics here. *which* type of Sybase database is this? The syntax suggests Sybase ASE, but the error message suggests Sybase IQ or SQL Anywhere. Please clarify.

Comment: In case of Sybase ASE, STR_REPLACE() does not work on TEXT datatypes.It only works on (VAR)CHAR.

Comment: It's Sybase ASE -12.5.2. Do you know a function that enables replacing the carriage returns with this database type ? Thanks.